# logarithmic and polynomial equation

Tags: logarithms

I have the following

$(1-a^x)/x=b$

Can this be solved for x ? (if yes, how, if not why)

I have gotten to many forms, but can't seem to isolate x.

Comment: Post some of the forms you found.

Comment: In general an equation can´t be solved algebraically for x, if x appears as a factor and as an exponent.

Comment: @AaronMaroja will post tomorrow morning as the calculus in on a colleagues paper (but it's mostly high-school stuff)

Comment: @calculus I got to this statement myself but was not satisfying as no demonstration was included (by the answer provider). this is why I stated the question like I did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> \begin{align} (1-a^x)/x&=b\quad (1) \end{align}

Assuming $x\ne 0,b\ne0,a>0,a\ne1$,
let $y=a^x\ (x=\ln(y)/\ln(a))$, then we can rewrite (1) as
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(y)}{1-y}&= \frac{\ln(a)}{b}. \quad (2) 
\end{align}

Since $\frac{\ln(y)}{1-y}<0$ for $y>0,y\ne 1$,
real solution for $y$ exists, if rhs of (2) is also negative,
that is, either $a\in(0,1),b>0$ or $a>1,b<0$.
Let $\frac{\ln(a)}{b}=w<0$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(y)}{1-y}&= w<0. \quad (3) 
\end{align}

Solution of (3) also splits into two cases, $|w|<1$ and $|w|>1$:
\begin{align}
y&=\begin{cases}
\operatorname{W}_{-1}(w\exp(w))/w,& |w|<1
\\
\operatorname{W}_{0}(w\exp(w))/w,&|w|>1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\operatorname{W}_{0},\operatorname{W}_{-1}$
are two real branches of the Lambert W function.

Finally, solution of (1) is:
\begin{align}
x&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{\ln\left(\operatorname{W}_{-1}(w\exp(w))/w\right)}{\ln(a)},& |w|<1
\\
\displaystyle\frac{\ln\left(\operatorname{W}_{0}(w\exp(w))/w\right)}{\ln(a)},& |w|>1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Example:

$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
\hline
a & b & w=\ln(a)/b & y & x & (1-a^x)/x
\\
\hline
0.01 & 1.0 & -4.60517 & 0.01050 & 0.98950 & 1.0 \\
0.80 & 15.0 & -0.01488 & 404.50727 & -26.90048 & 15.0 \\
3.00 & -0.2 & -5.49306 & 0.00421 & -4.97894 & -0.2 \\
4.00 & -0.2 & -6.93147 & 0.00098 & -4.99508 & -0.2 \\
7.00 & -5.0 & -0.38918 & 5.27112 & 0.85422 & -5.0
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $a,b>0$ and $a\neq 1$.

First rewrite the equation as
$$ \frac{1-\mathrm e^{x\ln a}}b=\frac{x \ln a}{\ln a}$$
and let us write $y=\frac{\ln a}b- x\ln a$. We get $y=\frac{\ln a}b\mathrm e^{\frac{\ln a}b-y}$ or
$$ya^y=\frac{\ln a}ba^{1/b}.$$
The solution of this equation is given, if $\boxed{\frac{\ln a}ba^{1/b}<-\frac1{\mathrm e}}$, by the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) : $y=W\left(\frac{\ln a}{b}a^{1/b}\right)$ or
$$x=\frac{1}b-\frac1{\ln a}W\left(\frac{\ln a}{b}a^{1/b}\right).$$

**EDIT** The same calculation actually works for $b<0$ with $a>1$. The framed condition remains identical.

Comment: I found the Lambert-W function but had no idea what to do with it (personal knowledge constraints)... will come back tomorrow (evening here) with a proper comment